# JScrollPane acompanhar o componente que está com foco

Tags: java, swing

Tenho uma tela com um `JSrollPane` e vários `JTextFields`. Quando mudo de textfield usando a tecla <kbd>tab</kbd>, o `JScrollPane` não acompanha caso o textfield que receber o foco estiver "para baixo da tela".

Queria que, quando mudasse o foco para um textfield que não esta aparecendo, o `JScrollPane` acompanhasse e descesse ou subisse dependendo para qual textfield eu mudar o foco.

Código para gerar a tela, é uma tela bem simples apenas com os textfield mesmo:

```
package newpackage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GridLayoutButtonsTest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private int qtButton = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GridLayoutButtonsTest frame = new GridLayoutButtonsTest();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public GridLayoutButtonsTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(464, 139));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            panel.add(gerarField());
        }
        scroll.setViewportView(panel);
        contentPane.add(scroll);

        pack();
    }

    public JTextField gerarField() {
        qtButton++;
        JTextField NewField = new JTextField(String.valueOf(qtButton));
        return NewField;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme retirado [desta pergunta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8245328/5524514), você pode registrar um [`PropertyChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html). *"focusOwner"* é o nome de uma propriedade [dentro da classe KeyboardFocusManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html#addPropertyChangeListener-java.lang.String-java.beans.PropertyChangeListener-) onde é registrado o proprietário do foco atual.

Este trecho de código será disparando sempre que um componente na janela ativa ganha foco, e se este novo componente a receber foco(campoFocado) for um `JTextComponent` e pertencer ao painel que comporta os campos de textos, irá mover a área visível do scroll para ele através do método [`scrollRectToVsisible()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible-java.awt.Rectangle-), juntamente com o foco.

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addPropertyChangeListener("focusOwner",
                new PropertyChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                        if (!(evt.getNewValue() instanceof JTextComponent)) {
                            return;
                        }
                        JTextComponent campoFocado = (JTextComponent) evt.getNewValue();
                        if (scroll.isAncestorOf(campoFocado)) {
                            panel.scrollRectToVisible(campoFocado.getBounds());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Veja funcionando:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>